# How do I use an extension installed in a different schema?

Tags: postgresql, schema, postgresql-extensions

I added an extension and my install shows the module installed,

```
mydb=# \dx
                                   List of installed extensions
 Name   | Version |   Schema   |                                  Description                            
--------+---------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------
pg_trgm | 1.0     | extensions | text similarity measurement and index searching based on trigrams
plpgsql | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
(2 rows)
```

But when I go to use it I'm getting an error,

```
mydb=# select similarity('hello','hell');
ERROR:  function similarity(unknown, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: select similarity('hello','hell');
           ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Is there any other step to use the functions the extension provides?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module was installed into the schema `extensions`. I guess that that schema is not in your search path and therefor the function is not found. Try

```
select extensions.similarity('hello','hell');
```

If you don't want to fully-qualify the function names you can simply add that schema to your search_path:

```
alter user your_pg_user set search_path = public,extensions;
```

If that still gives an error your Postgres user might not have the necessary privileges to call the functions. In that case log in as the superuser (typically `postgres`) and grant the priviliges:

```
grant all on schema extensions to your_pg_user;
```

Answer (score 3):

It should work. Here a psql protocol: (sorry, system is in german)

```
str@s131-intel:~> psql
psql (9.2.7)

strobel=# CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
CREATE EXTENSION
strobel=# \df
                                                          Liste der Funktionen
 Schema |          Name          | Ergebnisdatentyp |                            Argumentdatentypen                             |  Typ   
--------+------------------------+------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------
 public | flipper                | boolean          |                                                                           | normal
 public | gin_extract_query_trgm | internal         | text, internal, smallint, internal, internal, internal, internal          | normal
 public | gin_extract_value_trgm | internal         | text, internal                                                            | normal
 <cut>
 public | gtrgm_union            | integer[]        | bytea, internal                                                           | normal
 public | set_limit              | real             | real                                                                      | normal
 public | show_limit             | real             |                                                                           | normal
 public | show_trgm              | text[]           | text                                                                      | normal
 public | similarity             | real             | text, text                                                                | normal
 public | similarity_dist        | real             | text, text                                                                | normal
 public | similarity_op          | boolean          | text, text                                                                | normal
(20 Zeilen)

strobel=# select similarity('hallo', 'hello');
 similarity 
------------
   0.333333
(1 Zeile)
```

The error message gives a hint that your parameters were not seen as text, so maybe you wrote a backtick (accent grave) instead of apostrophe.